# Need to get the data with below format

Tags: sql, database-administration

Given the following Users and Groups tables:

```
[Users]
ID  Name        Groupid
1   User1       1
2   User2       2
3   User3       2
4   Manager1    3
5   Manager2    3

[Groups]
ID  Name            Managerid
1   Group1          4
2   Group2          5
3   ManagerGroup    NULL
```

i need to have the output like below:

```
User_Name, Group_Name,  Manager_Name
User1       Group1      Manager1
User2       Group2      Manager2
User3       Group2      Manager2
Manager1   ManagerGroup ‘’
Manager2   ManagerGroup ‘’
```

Comment: i don't know what type of join i shall use to get the results as formatted in my question

Comment: So, from your knowledge, what kind of query do you _think_ you might need? Read about the different types of joins and what results they make. Then try each type, and see if you get good results. At least try to get part of the result, even if you can't get all of it. If you don't _try_, you won't learn anything. If we just tell you all the answers, you won't truly learn anything either. In order to succeed, you sometimes have to fail first.

Comment: And anyway we are not a free write-my-code or do-my-thinking service. Will will _help_ you with your own attempt to solve the problem, once you have a specific question for us about joins, or about error messages etc. Here's are a couple of clues though: 1. You will probably need more than one join. 2. The same table can be joined more than once in a single query.

Comment: What's your question here?

Comment: sorry guys , i'm a new in SQL server and needed help i tried the following: select U.name as User_Name , G.name as Group_Name 
--,M.name as Manager_Name
from [Users] U inner join  [groups] G
on G.ID=U.groupid

Comment: Ok. But you didn't mention that before, or explain what result it produced, or what your current issue was. Anyway, read my last comment again, and maybe you will get a clue about what to do next...

Answer (score 0):

You were close with what you had, you just needed to join the managerid back to the users table.

```
SELECT u1.name as username, gr.name as Group_Name, u2.name as Manager_name from users u1 
INNER JOIN groups gr on u1.groupid = gr.id
INNER JOIN users u2 on u2.id = gr.managerid
```